# Past perfect/simple past in reported speech

Tags: grammaticality, indirect-speech

**Sentences:**

1. We told her that we **had given** her the money that **had been saved** from her husband's business. It was a pious fraud; she would have been distressed had she known we had collected it among ourselves.
2. We told her that we **had given** her the money that **was saved** from her husband's business. It was a pious fraud; she would have been distressed had she known we had collected it among ourselves.

**Question:**

The sequence of events is as follows:

1. The money in question was saved from her husband's business.
2. We gave her that money.
3. We told her about it.

Do the bolded tenses work in sentences #1 and #2 given the sequence of events? Thanks.

Comment: Past Perfect is natural for the first context *(**we had given**)*, but it's unnecessarily verbose for the second. In fact you don't really want/need *any* "auxiliary" verb there: *We told her we'd given her the money **saved** from her husband's business*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, does the following version also work in the context given: _We told her that we **gave** her the money that **had been saved** from her husband's business..._? Thanks.

Comment: It's a strange context, especially when converted to "reported speech", so I can't really say whether the *words* are "natural", because the *situation* isn't easy for me to imagine. It might help if you forget about the irrelevant reported speech aspect, and concentrate on the words "we" might have actually uttered. Ask yourself whether we said *We have given you...* OR *We gave you...* The answer to that question, which should be much easier to answer, is all you need to think about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks for the response. I thought the situation was easy to imagine because the sequence of events is presented in the original post: the saving happens first, then does the giving, and then the speaker tells the listener about the saving and the giving.